# Return promise from service to component

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I return documentId as a result from `websiteService.createWebsite` to `onConfirmButtonClick`:

```
  onConfirmButtonClick() {
    this.websiteService.createWebsite(this.websiteName).then(result => {
      if(result) {
        console.log(result);
        this.toastrService.success('Your website has been created.');
      }
    });
  }
```

In my website service:

```
  createWebsite(name) {
    this.afs.collection('websites', (ref) => ref.where('name', '==', name)
      .limit(1))
      .get()
      .subscribe(websites => {
        if (websites.size == 0) {
          const documentId = this.afs.createId();
          this.afs.doc(`websites/${ documentId }`).set({ name: name });
          return documentId;
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: What you're doing is wrong. You don't want to subscribe on each click. Do it just once (e.g. when initializing) and set the documentId to a model or state.

Comment: Not sure I follow, can you show me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing a few `return` statements in your `createWebsite` function.

Something like this:

```
  createWebsite(name) {
    return this.afs.collection('websites', (ref) => ref.where('name', '==', name)
      .limit(1))
      .get()
      .subscribe(websites => {
        if (websites.size == 0) {
          const documentId = this.afs.createId();
          return documentId;
        }
      });
  }
```

With these two added `return` statements, the `documentId` will bubble up, and be returned from `createWebsite`, where the `then()` block of the calling code can then pick it up.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious as to why this was downvoted. What about the above point - "what you're doing is wrong. You don't want to subscribe on each click. Do it just once (e.g. when initializing) and set the documentId to a model or state.", do I need to take it into account?

Comment: Also with regards to `this.afs.doc(`websites/${ documentId }`).set({ name: name });`, the actual creation of the document, I get the message `promise from set is ignored`, is this something I should worry about?